# Kitchen .kitchen.yml multiple-line environment variable

Tags: ruby, yaml, test-kitchen

With Kitchen I am trying to define an attribute with a multiple-line environment variable using `.kitchen.yml` such as :

```
attributes:
  foo:
    ssh:
      key_private: <%= ENV['CHEF_SSH_KEY_PRIVATE'] %>
```

The multi-line `CHEF_SSH_KEY_PRIVATE` variable looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This method works perfectly fine with single-line variables, however the file cannot be parsed when using multi-line variable. I suspect the "compiled" file does not have proper indentation, but I cannot set indentation directly on the variable as it may be used in other YAML files requiring a different indentation level.

How can I properly use multi-line environment variable in YAML without parsing issues?

Comment: would it suffice to store a single-line double-quoted value in the variable? like `"---BEGIN---\n...\n...\n---END---"`

Comment: Well done, works like a charm thanks! I was missing the double quotes. If you would post this solution as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the environment variable to contain a double-quoted single-line string with escaped newlines, like

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

This is safe to include at any position of a YAML document where a content node is expected.

Comment: This works, but it feels like a work-around.
Since multi-line keys can be considerably long and you lose the readability.
On top of it, yaml does supports multi-line strings,

Comment: @Aditya Well the *proper* solution would be to write a YAML-aware templating engine, but I don't see that happening, considering the fragmented YAML user base (Ruby with this ruby templating thing vs. Python with Jinja vs. other frameworks that offer post-parse solutions).